# Firefox displays surprising results on img tags with zoom styles

Tags: firefox

I have a piece of code

```
<img src="xxx" style="zoom:80%" />
```

It is displayed as expected on chrome.

But on Firefox, this picture is not zoomed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

CSS `zoom` is non standard, and is not supported by Firefox. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

You could try `transform`:

```
   <img src="xxx" style="transform: scale(80%);" />
```